# Install Wikipedia and its API Locally

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Wikipedia [Search API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page) has usage limits.

I can get the source code for the API server [from here](https://git.wikimedia.org/tree/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/HEAD/includes%2Fapi), but there is no documentation about which Wikipeida format it takes or how to deploy it.

Any help regarding this matter is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic steps:

1. Download the XML dump
2. Download the mediawiki package (the wiki itself from https://git.wikimedia.org/tree/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/HEAD/includes%2Fapi)
3. Install Apache with Php and mysql (any AMP package), place mediawiki in the www folder.
4. Install/Configure the media wiki. It will be empty with no pages.
5. Download mwdumper jar, follow instructions in http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MWDumper to import the Wikipedia XML into mysql database of the locally installed mediawiki wiki. This will take a few hours.
6. The API can be accessed, e.g., using http:// localhost/mediawiki/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Albert